# Get "insert_id" for one to one relationship in Flask, SqlAlchemy

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert a new row through sqlalchemy.  The parent table (Milestone) has a child table called Funding. Both tables share a relationship through a column called milestone_id.  It is a one to one relationship.

I have looked it up, but I can't figure out how to reference the milestone_id when INSERTING a new row in the Funding table.  The parent ID is an autoincrement.  I am using Flask and SqlAlchemy.

models:

```
 class Milestone(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "**************"

   milestone_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('stlines_startups.company_id'))
   milestone_date = db.Column(db.Integer)
   snapshots = db.relationship('Snapshot', uselist=False, primaryjoin='Milestone.milestone_id==Snapshot.milestone_id', backref='milestone')
   fundraising = db.relationship('Funding', uselist=False, primaryjoin='Milestone.milestone_id==Funding.milestone_id', backref='milestone')

   def __init__(self, milestone_id, company_id, milestone_date, snapshots = [], fundraising = []):
    self.milestone_id = milestone_id
    self.company_id = company_id
    self.milestone_date = milestone_date
    self.snapshots = snapshots
    self.fundraising = fundraising

class Funding(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "**************************"

   funding_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   funding_type = db.Column(db.Text)
   funding_message = db.Column(db.Text)
   funding_amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
   milestone_source = db.Column(db.Text)
   company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('stlines_milestones.company_id'))
   milestone_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('stlines_milestones.milestone_id'))
   user_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
   funding_timestamp = db.Column(db.Integer)

def __init__(self, funding_id, funding_type, funding_message, funding_amount, milestone_source, milestone_id, company_id, user_id, funding_timestamp):
    self.funding_id = funding_id
    self.funding_type = funding_type
    self.funding_message = funding_message
    self.funding_amount = funding_amount
    self.milestone_source = milestone_source
    self.milestone_id = milestone_id
    self.company_id = company_id
    self.user_id = user_id
    self.funding_timestamp = funding_timestamp
```

Alchemy Query:

```
@app.route('/_add_funding')
def add_funding():
    funding_type = request.args.get('funding_stage', '', type=str)
    funding_message = request.args.get('funding_message', '', type=str)
    funding_amount = request.args.get('funding_amount', 0, type=int)
    milestone_source = request.args.get('milestone_source', '', type=str)
    milestone_date = request.args.get('milestone_date', '', type=str)
    company_id = request.args.get('company_id', '', type=int)

    milestone_date_final = datetime.datetime.strptime(milestone_date, '%B %d, %Y')

    ''' In this line, I try to reference milestone_id with new_milestone.milestone_id, but nothing shows up in the database '''
    new_funding = Funding('', funding_type=funding_type, funding_message=funding_message, funding_amount=funding_amount, milestone_source=milestone_source, company_id=company_id, milestone_id=new_milestone.milestone_id, user_id='1', funding_timestamp=milestone_date_final)
    new_milestone = Milestone('', company_id=company_id, milestone_date=milestone_date_final, snapshots=None, fundraising=new_funding)
    db.session.add(new_milestone)
    output = new_milestone.milestone_id
    db.session.commit()

    return jsonify(result=output)
```

How can I tell SqlAlchemy to use the auto generated milestone_id from the milestone table when insert the funding information in the funding table?  Should these be two separate queries?

**Update:**

I took up the advice from ThiefMaster about using the flush function, but I'm still getting an error:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_milestone' referenced before assignment

here's the updated code:

```
@app.route('/_add_funding')
def add_funding():
    funding_type = request.args.get('funding_stage', '', type=str)
    funding_message = request.args.get('funding_message', '', type=str)
    funding_amount = request.args.get('funding_amount', 0, type=int)
    milestone_source = request.args.get('milestone_source', '', type=str)
    milestone_date = request.args.get('milestone_date', '', type=str)
    company_id = request.args.get('company_id', '', type=int)

    milestone_date_final = datetime.datetime.strptime(milestone_date, '%B %d, %Y')
    ''' In this line, I try to reference milestone_id with new_milestone.milestone_id, but nothing shows up in the database '''
    new_funding = Funding('', funding_type=funding_type, funding_message=funding_message, funding_amount=funding_amount, milestone_source=milestone_source, company_id=company_id, milestone_id=new_milestone.milestone_id, user_id='1', funding_timestamp=milestone_date_final)
    new_milestone = Milestone('', company_id=company_id, milestone_date=milestone_date_final, snapshots=None, fundraising=new_funding)
    db.session.add(new_milestone)
    db.session.commit()
    db.session.flush()
    output = new_milestone.milestone_id

    return jsonify(result=output)
```

any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to `commit()` and then to ask for `flush()` as `commit()` calls `flush()` by itself. The idea is that when you do `flush()`, SQLAlchemy will populate the value for the autoincrement column thus you are able to access the value of autoincrement so that you could populate the parent_id from the child table when adding a new child.
Note: When you add records to your SQLAlchemy session it does not (yet) writes records to DB. It will do so all at once after you fire commit or flush. This helps with performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an exact solution.  If anyone is wondering, I ended up working around it by executing SQL directly.  It's not ideal, but it gets the job done for now.  I ended up inserting on row at a time, here's the code below:

```
@app.route('/_add_funding')
def add_funding():
    funding_type = request.args.get('funding_stage', '', type=str)
    funding_message = request.args.get('funding_message', '', type=str)
    funding_amount = request.args.get('funding_amount', 0, type=int)
    milestone_source = request.args.get('milestone_source', '', type=str)
    milestone_date = request.args.get('milestone_date', '', type=str)
    company_id = request.args.get('company_id', '', type=int)

    milestone_date_final =  time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(milestone_date, '%B %d, %Y').timetuple())

    sql = "INSERT INTO ******** (`milestone_id`,`company_id`, `milestone_date`) VALUES ('','{}','{}')".format(company_id, milestone_date_final)
    result = db.engine.execute(sql)

    milestone_id = result.lastrowid 

    sql = "INSERT INTO ****** (`funding_id`,`funding_type`, `funding_message`, `funding_amount`, `milestone_source`, `company_id`, `milestone_id`, `user_id`, `funding_timestamp`) VALUES ('','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','1', '{}')".format(funding_type, funding_message, funding_amount, milestone_source, company_id, milestone_id, milestone_date_final)
    result = db.engine.execute(sql)

    output = result.lastrowid
    return jsonify(result=output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `db.session.flush()` after your `db.session.add(..)` call. This will result in the INSERT being sent to the database and afterwards you'll have acess to the ID.